# Why is my code using Parallel::ForkManager producing zombies?

Tags: perl, fork, zombie-process

A piece of code I'm writing uses [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager) and I'm noticing it is creating many zombies as the script runs. I'm wondering if I'm missing something when it comes to the `wait_all_children`.

```
my $fork_manager = new Parallel::ForkManager->($ENV{CPUS})

for(my $i = 0; $i < scalar @plates; $i++){
    my $offset = get_full_plate_offsets(@{$plates[$i]});
    make_path(File::Spec->catfile($tmp_dir, $i));
    foreach my $cell (keys %{$offset}){
        my($x, $y) = @{$offset->{$cell}};
        $fork_manager->start("$cell @ $x, $y") and next;
        my $out_file = File::Spec->catfile($tmp_dir, $i, "$cell.jpg");
        my $out_text = File::Spec->catfile($tmp_dir, $i, "$cell.txt");
        split_file($input_jpg, [$x, $y], $out_file);
        my $result = do_something($out_file);
        open(my $FH, '>', $out_text);
        print $FH "$result\n";
        $fork_manager->finish;
    }
    $fork_manager->wait_all_children;
}
```

Also a clarifying question. Zombies are always bad right?

At first I was under the impression that zombie processes are just processes that haven't been recovered by their parent yet. Now I'm wondering if my code is not waiting on the children at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

P::FM only reaps when `start` is called and the maximum number of children are running, and when `wait_children` or `wait_all_children` are called. Children that exit become zombies until then.

You will never have more children (including zombies) than specified, so the temporary presence of zombies isn't a bad thing<sup>[1]</sup>. The only catch is that the `run_on_finish` handler will only be executed when the child process is reaped, so this indicates that it's not being called as soon as possible.

I believe you can use the following to reap children sooner:

```
$SIG{CHLD} = sub { $pm->wait_children };
```

---

1. See [Is a persistent zombie process sign of a bug?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74028/is-a-persistent-zombie-process-sign-of-a-bug) for a general answer.

Comment: You don't think Parallel::ForkManager already uses the SIGCHLD handler?

Comment: Great, I was concerned there was a code smell re: zombies. That perhaps I had missed a detail about shared state. As you said it could be that the children are completing before the wait_all_children is reached. Interesting bit about the on_finish, I'll keep that in mind as I see myself using more of ForkManager.

Comment: @mob, It doesn't (except under very specific circumstances in a very localized area). If it did, the zombies would be reap immediately upon child exit as the line I added does.